# Unable to initialize YEDIS API with yugabyted

Tags: yugabytedb

I have successfully installed yugabyte on WSL2 using yugabyted following the steps from:
https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/reference/configuration/yugabyted/
can you please advice me on how to enable YEDIS API too? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the yb-admin utility to enable YEDIS as per the following:

`./bin/yb-admin --master_addresses <list of master addresses of the form IP:PORT, the PORT is generally 7100> setup_redis_table`

After this, you can enter the shell using:

`./bin/redis-cli`

and try PING. Once you are inside the shell you can use the following reference for further APIs: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/yedis/quick-start/

If you want to drop the table you can use:

`./bin/yb-admin --master_addresses <list of master addresses of the form IP:PORT, the PORT is generally 7100> drop_redis_table`

[Issue to track](https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/9119) to make this available in `yugabyted`.